# Kafka will not take in large files (30+ mb) within NiFi

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I am using Apache NiFi, and when attempting to get Kafka to take a text file that is about 30mb, without giving an error, the PutKafka processor refuses to take the data sent from my GetFile processor.

[Here is my config for my PutKafka Processor:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwh9D.png)

[Here's what happens when I try to put the file through to the PutKafka processor:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaNBw.png)

I have tried changing a few of the values within the PutKafka processor to no avail. This same setup was successful when sending a very small text file, but it was not delimited by the pipe.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Apache NiFi are you using?  Can you try having the buffer and record sizes both at 50MB please.  Also, what is the error that occurs when you try?  The image for that appears like it was not the one you intended.

Comment: You has stopped putKafka processor in second image :S

Answer (score 2):

Could you please look at the logs and see if there are relevant stack traces there and paste them here. My suspicion is that you are over the max buffer size and Kafka itself fails, so the message never reaches the topic. For example, while you seem to be overriding 'max.request.size' your 'buffer.memory' is way less then your request size. 
In any event, the stack trace would help.